# rsyslog stopped creating pid file after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: configuration, systemd, rsyslog

After upgrading from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS rsyslog stopped writing its PID into `/(var/)run/rsyslogd.pid` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service` and remove `-iNONE` option from `ExecStart` line.
Then run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart rsyslog` and PID file should back.

man rsyslogd(8) says:

```
-i pid file
              Specify an alternative pid file instead of the default one.
              This option must be used if multiple instances of rsyslogd
              should run on a single machine. To disable writing a pid file,
              use the reserved name "NONE" (all upper case!), so "-iNONE".
```

== EDIT ==

As @Ondrej Simek suggested below instead of doing a manual edit of the service file you can use `systemctl edit` and write

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
```

After you save and close your editor the change should be applied to the service and the service restarted with PID file created. Good thing about this approach is that this change should survive `rsyslog` upgrade because it creates new `/etc/systemd/system/rsyslog.service.d/override.conf` file which overrides everything that is in `/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service`.

Comment: You should use `systemctl edit` instead. Run `systemctl edit rsyslog.service` and write `[Unit]<new line>ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n` (replace `<new line>` with new line). Then proceed with `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart rsyslog`.

Comment: @OndrejSimek, are you sure it shouldn't be `[Service]<new line>ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n` (`[Service]` instead of `[Unit]`)?

Comment: Thanks for correction - yup, you're right.

Comment: Actually, @OndrejSimek, there is another line missing: `ExecStart=` that clears the value of this property first. Only then we can overwrite it with `/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n`. Otherwise `systemctl` throws `rsyslog.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. `.